# C++ library to populate SSL stream with valid HTTP requests

Tags: c++, boost, httprequest, boost-asio

I am using Boost.Asio [ssl streams](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_66_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/ssl__stream.html), and got a working encrypted socket from which I can send and receive bytes.

I successfully did a GET request with the following code :

```
// Construct HTTP request (using vanilla std::ostream)
std::ostream request_stream(&request);
request_stream << "GET  / HTTP/1.0\r\n";
request_stream << "Host: " << argv[1] << "\r\n";
...
// Send request
ssl::stream<tcp::socket> socket
boost::asio::write(socket, request);
```

And I would now *love* to find a small C++ library  that would provide an **easy way to get the ostream loaded with a valid HTTP request** !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're already using Boost.Asio, consider using Boost.Beast which is a low-level HTTP library. Example of sending a GET request using Boost.Beast:

```
using namespace boost::beast;

// Set up an HTTP GET request message
http::request<http::empty_body> req{http::verb::get, "/", 11};
req.set(http::field::host, "www.example.com");
req.set(http::field::user_agent, "Beast/1.0);

// Send the HTTP request to the remote host
http::write(socket, req);
```

The full example is here:
https://github.com/boostorg/beast/blob/master/example/http/client/sync/http_client_sync.cpp

Beast is available in Boost versions 1.66 and later. Here is the documentation page, which includes many examples:
http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_66_0/libs/beast/doc/html/index.html

If you **really** want to write the HTTP request to a `std::ostream`, Beast supports `operator<<` for HTTP messages (it is mainly there for debugging), but I think you are better off just writing it directly to the `ip::tcp::socket` or `ssl::stream` using Beast.

Comment: That seems just great, I'll check it out & accept your answer when I'll get it working. Thumbs up !

Comment: Working fine ! How come i am able to write with the boost::beast::http write method to a boost::asio::ssl::stream ? Common parent class ?

Comment: @AlexandreRozier Because `ssl::stream` and `tcp::ip::socket` both meet the requirements of SyncStream and AsyncStream. Beast's stream algorithms are templated, and work with any type that meets those requirements. They are documented here (click the links on the page) http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_66_0/libs/beast/doc/html/beast/concepts/streams.html